# Is there an English thesaurus resource that I can access using Perl?

Tags: perl, thesaurus

I'd like to use Perl to search through an offline thesaurus. I don't know if this is possible, or what the mechanics of achieving this may be

I'd like be able to

- Have a downloaded thesaurus on a machine
- Write a Perl program that searches through the downloaded thesaurus and spits back minimal output.

For example

```
=============================
Synoynms for: wiggle
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
wave   waggle   wag   twitch
twist  squirm   shimmy
jiggle jerk
=============================
```

I noticed that there's a [`Biblio::Thesaurus`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Biblio::Thesaurus) which seemed promising, but I'm totally lost as to how this module would be used unless there's a universal (or at least popular) thesaurus for the English language in ISO format freely available for download somewhere

I guess I'm looking for

- A thesaurus for English in ISO format
- A way of navigating this data using Perl

Comment: Are you looking for English English or American English?

Comment: [`Lingua::Wordnet`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Lingua::Wordnet) looks promising. There's a fairly [detailed article](http://www.foo.be/docs/tpj/issues/vol5_2/tpj0502-0006.html) in the Perl Journal describing its usage.

Comment: There's also the [Moby Thesaurus](http://icon.shef.ac.uk/Moby/mthes.html), which is in the public domain.

Comment: The Perl part of this could really be as simple as a dictionary hash with arrays of synonyms as values e.g. `$thesaurus{wiggle} = [qw(wave waggle wag)]`. The offline part then would just be a matter of finding and probably some amount of transforming a publicly available data set into that Perl hash. I don't know offhand how involved the latter would be but OpenOffice and Wiktionary both have downloadable dumps.

Comment: Borodin - American English

ThisSuitIsBlackNot - I'm looking into Wordnet I noticed there's a dictionary, but didn't notice if there was a thesaurus or not. I have also noticed Moby out there.

swomabsent - I agree, if there were a large thesaurus available for download in *some* structured format, using Perl to navigate then just becomes a coding task.

Comment: My take on all this though: I'm just surprised that, in this day and age, there isn't a quick and automatic answer to this problem i.e. "Oh yeah, go download the Oxford English Dictionary XML file and use Purple::Nurple to parse through it" In other words, it seems like this would be a not common (but certainly not *rare*) need out there in the world. I'm surprised I'm getting pointed to some darker corners to solve it, and not a big bright one. :-/

- G

Answer (score 0):

For better or worse, the solution I'm working with is...

1) Downloaded the Moby Thesaurus. Data there is simple...

```
i.e. root word,synonym 1, synonym 2, synonym 3, etc.
e.g. hamburger, BLT, Dogwood sandwich, cheeseburger, etc.
```

2) Used plain-old Perl, no special module, to parse and repeat searches through the data - once it's loaded in memory.

- G